# Avoid Panel resizing on TextField Validator error - Vaadin

Tags: jakarta-ee, vaadin

I created a simple Sign in form wich has some required fields with validator.

My field form layout is like that :

```
    _________________________
    |  My SO Panel          |
     -----------------------
    |   _______    _______  |
    |  |_______|  |_______| |
    |   _______    _______  |
    |  |_______|  |_______| |
    |_______________________|
```

If the user sets an invalid value in one of the fields that are on the left part of the form, a red ! appears on the right of the field, so all of the other fields are moving to the right.

in my Panel i added a HorizontalLayout with contains two verticalLayout (one for left, one for right). This horizontalLayout has spacing and the two verticalLayouts are having it too.

How can I do to avoid moving the right fields when my validator shows his !  ?

Comment: Do you show the captions of the fields? Usually the red ! is appended to that text....

Comment: no i don't, i notice wich content is needed in every field with setInputPrompt("Content")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming, that you actually want to have both the `required` and the `componentError` there, you would have to give them some room to breath.  one way could be to just set a width for the horizontal layout, that is larger than two times the textfields and the markers.  with a 50/50 split this would just keep some space to the second "cell" of the horizontal layout and the change of size would not matter.

If you are using 100% layout, this might not be that easy.  in that case you could give the caption (the container, where both markers are show) give a fixed width.

So e.g. you provide some class for your container (`fixed-width-caption`) and then add

```
 .fixed-width-caption .v-caption { width: 40px }
```

This gives all the captions a fixed width of 40px, which would be enough at least in my example with a standard Valo setup to be stable with both markers.

Comment: Worked like a charm, i just added a margin on left side of the left part to center the confirm button.